My GPS Tracker Project Device Stops Working After 1-2 Months. Ublox MAX M10S, BMI270, JDY-23, STM32
I built a GPS tracker with an IMU that sends data via BLE 5.0. The device includes a button for power control: a single press turns it on, and another press turns it off (not a toggle switch). Initially, everything works perfectly, but after 1-2 months, the device stops sending data and cannot be turned off anymore.
I suspect the issue might be with the GPS module. My code includes a logic that halts the device if the GPS cannot establish communication at the expected baud rate. The module is initially configured to use a baud rate of 460800 every time it powers on. However, I'm wondering if the GPS module might reset itself to the default 9600 baud over time, potentially due to some internal reset or configuration loss.
To handle this, I implemented a function that cycles through three baud rates (460800, 115200, 9600) every time the device powers on. It tries each rate until communication with the GPS module is established. While this works for now, I am uncertain if it will remain reliable in the long term.
Does anyone have insights into:
Why the GPS module might revert to the default baud rate over time?
Best practices to ensure stable operation over an extended period?
If there are alternative approaches to mitigate such issues?
Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!
JDY-23 BLE Datasheet (I am adding this because its not popular):
text
Here is my updated code:
#include <HardwareSerial.h>
#include <SparkFun_BMI270_Arduino_Library.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include "STM32TimerInterrupt.h"
#include "STM32_ISR_Timer.h"

SFE_UBLOX_GNSS_SERIAL myGNSS;
BMI270 imu;
const uint8_t i2cAddress = BMI2_I2C_SEC_ADDR; // 0x69

HardwareSerial gserial(USART1);
HardwareSerial bserial(USART3);

#define ADC_MIN_VALUE 80
#define ADC_MAX_VALUE 120
#define BATTERY_MAX_VOLTAGE 4.25  // Maximum battery voltage (4.25V)

// Pin configurations
const int chipSelect = PA4; // SS pin

#define DEVICE_SERIAL_NUMBER "24A1073" // VT1   -   2408   -      0A                  -           1001
                                          //  product   year/month   batch/party                        number
                                          //   name       yymm     0a,0b representing 1,2,3 ...         


// Interval in microseconds for 20Hz (50ms)
#define TIMER_INTERVAL_US      15000UL

// Create STM32 hardware timer object
STM32Timer ITimer(TIM2); // Use TIM2 or any other available timer

void setup() {

    pinMode(PA12, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(PA11, INPUT_PULLUP); 
    pinMode(PB12, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(PB13, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(PB14, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(PA12, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(PB12, LOW); //YELLOW
    digitalWrite(PB13, HIGH); //MAGENTA
    digitalWrite(PB14, HIGH); //CYAN
    
    bserial.begin(9600);
    changeBLEDeviceProp(); //OPEN THIS ONLY IN FIRST BUILD
    delay(600);
    bserial.begin(115200);

    Wire.begin(I2C1);
    Wire.setClock(400000); // Set I2C clock to 400kHz

    // Initialize BMI270
    while (imu.beginI2C(i2cAddress) != BMI2_OK) {
        bserial.println("Error: BMI270 not connected, check wiring and I2C address!");
        delay(100);
    }
    bserial.println("BMI270 connected!");
    delay(100);

    // Attempt GNSS initialization
    initializeGNSS();

    // Initialize ADC pin for battery measurement
    pinMode(PA0, OUTPUT);  // BAT_ADC_EN
    digitalWrite(PA0, LOW);  // Initially disable ADC
    pinMode(PA1, INPUT_ANALOG);

// Timer Interrupt Setup
    if (ITimer.attachInterruptInterval(TIMER_INTERVAL_US, gpsTimerCallback)) {
        bserial.println("Timer interrupt started.");
    } else {
        bserial.println("Failed to set timer interrupt!");
    }
}

void gpsTimerCallback() {
    imu.getSensorData();
    sendSensorData();

    if (digitalRead(PA11) == LOW) {
        delay(100);
        handleShutdownSequence();
    }
}

void loop() {
  retryGNSS();
}

void initializeGNSS() {
    const uint32_t baudRates[] = {460800,9600,115200};
    size_t baudRateCount = sizeof(baudRates) / sizeof(baudRates[0]);
    bool gnssInitialized = false;
    const uint32_t timeoutMs = 50;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < baudRateCount; i++) {
        gserial.begin(baudRates[i]);
        gserial.setTimeout(timeoutMs);
        bserial.printf("Trying GNSS baud rate: %lu\n", baudRates[i]);
        
        if (myGNSS.begin(gserial)) { // GNSS başlatmayı dene
            if (myGNSS.getPVT()) { // PVT verisini kontrol et
                bserial.printf("GNSS initialized at baud rate: %lu\n", baudRates[i]);
                gnssInitialized = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        gserial.end(); // Close UART and try the next baud rate
    }

    if (!gnssInitialized) {
        bserial.println("Warning: GNSS not initialized. Retrying in the background...");
    } 
    else {
        // Set GNSS to a higher baud rate for performance
        if (myGNSS.setSerialRate(460800)) { 
            gserial.end();
            gserial.begin(460800);
        } else {
            bserial.println(F("Failed to change GNSS baud rate"));
        }
        // Configure GNSS settings
        myGNSS.setUART1Output(COM_TYPE_UBX);
        myGNSS.setDynamicModel(DYN_MODEL_AUTOMOTIVE);
        delay(100);
        myGNSS.enableGNSS(true, SFE_UBLOX_GNSS_ID_GPS); 
        myGNSS.enableGNSS(true, SFE_UBLOX_GNSS_ID_GALILEO);
        myGNSS.enableGNSS(true, SFE_UBLOX_GNSS_ID_QZSS);  
        myGNSS.enableGNSS(true, SFE_UBLOX_GNSS_ID_SBAS);
        myGNSS.enableGNSS(false, SFE_UBLOX_GNSS_ID_GLONASS);
        myGNSS.enableGNSS(false, SFE_UBLOX_GNSS_ID_BEIDOU);
        myGNSS.setMeasurementRate(50);
        myGNSS.setNavigationFrequency(20);
        delay(50);
        myGNSS.saveConfiguration();
    }
}

void retryGNSS() {
    static unsigned long lastRetryTime = 0;
    const unsigned long retryInterval = 5000; // Retry every 5 seconds

    if (!myGNSS.getPVT() && (millis() - lastRetryTime > retryInterval)) {
        bserial.println("Retrying GNSS initialization...");
        initializeGNSS();
        lastRetryTime = millis();
    }
}


// Send sensor data over BLE
void sendSensorData() {
    String data;
    data.reserve(128);

    float latitude = myGNSS.getLatitude() / 10000000.0;
    float longitude = myGNSS.getLongitude() / 10000000.0;
    float altitude = myGNSS.getAltitude() / 1000.0; // Convert mm to meters
    float speed = myGNSS.getGroundSpeed() * 0.0036;
    byte SIV = myGNSS.getSIV();
    byte fixType = myGNSS.getFixType();
    int fixStatus = (fixType == 3) ? 2 : (fixType == 2) ? 1 : 0;
    float pdop = myGNSS.getPDOP() / 100.0;
    float heading = myGNSS.getHeading() / 100000.0;
    float batteryPercentage = getBatteryPercentage();
    int32_t horizontalAcc = myGNSS.getHorizontalAccEst();  // in millimeters
    int32_t verticalAcc = myGNSS.getVerticalAccEst();      // in millimeters
    float positionAccuracy = sqrt(sq(horizontalAcc) + sq(verticalAcc)) / 1000.0;  // Convert to meters

    data += "A:" + String(DEVICE_SERIAL_NUMBER);
    data += ";B:" + String(latitude, 7);
    data += ";C:" + String(longitude, 7);
    data += ";D:" + String(altitude,1);
    data += ";E:" + String(speed, 1);
    data += ";F:" + String(SIV);
    data += ";G:" + String(fixStatus);
    data += ";H:" + String(imu.data.accelX, 2);
    data += ";I:" + String(imu.data.accelY, 2);
    data += ";J:" + String(imu.data.accelZ, 2);
    data += ";K:" + String(imu.data.gyroX, 0);
    data += ";L:" + String(imu.data.gyroY, 0);
    data += ";M:" + String(imu.data.gyroZ, 0);
    data += ";N:" + String(batteryPercentage, 0);
    data += ";O:" + String(heading,0);
    data += ";P:" + String(positionAccuracy, 1) + ";";

    bserial.println(data);
    bserial.flush();
}

// Handle device shutdown
void handleShutdownSequence() {
    static bool shuttingDown = false;
    if (!shuttingDown) {
        shuttingDown = true;
        digitalWrite(PB14, LOW);
        digitalWrite(PB12, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(PB13, HIGH);
        delay(1000);
        digitalWrite(PA12, LOW);
        shuttingDown = false;
    }
}

// Get battery percentage
float getBatteryPercentage() {
    static const float ADC_SCALE = BATTERY_MAX_VOLTAGE / ADC_MAX_VALUE;
    digitalWrite(PA0, HIGH);
    int adcValue = analogRead(PA1);
    digitalWrite(PA0, LOW);
    float voltage = adcValue * ADC_SCALE;
    float percentage = ((voltage - 3.0) / (BATTERY_MAX_VOLTAGE - 3.0)) * 100.0;
    return constrain(percentage, 0, 100);
}


void changeBLEDeviceProp() {
    bserial.print("AT\r\n");
    delay(500);
    bserial.print("AT+NAMEGPS-ILKER\r\n");
    delay(500);
    bserial.print("AT+MTU2\r\n");  // Set MTU size TO 128b
    delay(500);
    bserial.print("AT+BAUD0\r\n");
    delay(500);
}


forget to write this here:
#include <SparkFun_u-blox_GNSS_v3.h>
this was in the code also

Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, and read "[ask]" and other pages of the [help]. -- You can [edit] your question to add new information or corrections. Do not use comments, this is not a forum.

@ilkerçetinkaya just edit the question to add missing information.  Do not put it in a comment.

@Clifford thx I will do that. Any help about the problem?

It does sound like a problem with the specific GPS rather than a software problem. All "products" of the Arduino flavour are infamous for sudden EMC problems out of the blue. What standards did you EMC test it against?
